# Save changes back to XMLTYPE column value after editing in external XML editor in Toad

Tags: xml, toad

I understand that Toad no longer supports XMLType column editing directly due to some Unicode issue.

I actually quite like the idea of using a powerful external XML Editor to do this for all the perks that brings.

I have managed to set the XML Editor exe in Toad so it pops up on double-clicking the column value.

However I can't seem to find a simple way of saving changes made in the external editor back to the XMLType Column Value, even copy paste doesn't work. (I'd rather not write an UPDATE statement or equivalent).

Am I missing something?

I am using Toad 11.0 and have tried to use Notepad++ and Oxygen 13.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain the down-vote...

Answer (score 2):

Ive had the same issue. The theory is TOAD writes out a temp file that your editor opens and on save it writes the file back to the DB. In my experience this just didnt work. Not sure if it depends on the app your using, or perhaps UAC in windows no idea, it jsut didnt work.

However, youll find that with TOAD 11 the default built-in XML editor has been restored. Im on TOAD 11.0.0.116 and using the editor quite happily.